# Constraint Layout & Flow for showing html?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to achieve something as in the picture. I have a lot of HTML files in my app for which I want to achieve individual highlighting, adding annotations etc.

I'm unable to achieve the desired result though. My plan is to add each individual sentence to a database and then have some additional fields along each row for formatting etc. I can't understand how to chain up the textviews though. I've tried out a few experiments of my own for a few hours now.

Can anyone help me with this, please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason to use `ConstraintLayout` here.
One `TextView` should be enough.

To set different text styles on particular words or sentences, use Spans: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568

Comment: Thanks, Piotr for your feedback. How do I go about selecting the text on a click event. That is a tricky part where the entire sentence needs to be selected and then the options for highlighting are presented to the user. I am trying to serve pages from a book with page numbers and page dividers. In effect, it should look like a book.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks, Piotr, for pointing me in the correct direction. After a lot of faffing around, I've finally managed to achieve everything using SpannableString and ClickableSpan. Anyone wanting further explanation on this topic, please get in touch with me and I'd be more than happy to help. I do not wish to post my code here as it consists of a lot of my personal software code as well. But if required, I'm happy to strip it down and post it.